# Clean architecture Android: where to do object mapping

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I am trying to build an android app based on bob's clean architecture. I have read many articles about the same. Finally following [this](http://five.agency/android-architecture-part-4-applying-clean-architecture-on-android-hands-on/), [this](http://macoscope.com/blog/model-view-presenter-architecture-in-android-applications/#main). I have read about repository pattern from [here](https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006).

The app is a simple Note(/Ideas) taking app. I am packaging by features.

[image: package structure]

Lets take the case to get all notes/ideas from the database.I have a usecase/interactor `GetAllIdeasUseCase` which will return list of (observer)  business objects `IdeasEntity`. This uses the `IdeasRepository` to get a list of ideas. The `IdeaLocalStore` is an repository to database. The IdeasRepository currently just chooses between the `IdeaLocalRepository` and `IdeaCloudRepository` and will call the corresponding function on them.

To create the IdeasEntity, I would need to use multiple db models hence multiple calls to IdeaLocalStore. And i would need to combine them.

So the **question is** where should i do this combination/mapping. Should i do it in the `IdesRepository` or should i do it inside the usecase ?

Comment: Entity should be created in a single read, let the database do that job.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion you should do it in repository. Repository must be responsible to provide you fully created object.
There is a good book that describe this approach - Domain-Driven Design (
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/eric-evans-on-repositories.html).

Quote from the book:
'Thus the core purpose of the repository is to encapsulate persistence. The client should appear to be simply using an entity collection and all the details of object relational mapping and specific data access APIs should be hidden behind that collection like interface. Repositories should only be provided for aggregate roots'